# Typesetting neat tables in latex

Tags: tables

How can I typeset the following table to look neat and professional?

```
\begin{table}[!h]
\caption{A summary of classification results on the free flowing traffic dataset}
\begin{tabular}{|p{1.7 cm}|p{1.7 cm}|p{1.7 cm}|p{1.7 cm}|p{1.5 cm}|p{1.5 cm}|p{1.5 cm}|p{1.6 cm}|p{1.5 cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Total no. of vehicles used for classification} & \textbf{No. of small vehicles used for classification} & \textbf{No. of medium vehicles used for classification} & \textbf{No. of large vehicles used for classification} & \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\textbf{Classification accuracy}}\\ 
\cline{5-9}
& & & & K-nearest neighbor classifier & Nearest centroid classifier & Naïve Bayes Classifier & Multilayer neural network classifier & Ensemble classifier\\
\hline
952 & 594 & 199 & 159 & 90.9\% & 89.4\% & 91.1\% & 89.3\% & 91.8\% \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab 4.2}
```

Comment: My immediate thought is to at least replace the four first explanations with something shorter, maybe some abbreviations.

Comment: Oh, and [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you begin by (a) providing more structure to the header and (b) eliminating repetitive elements. Separately, you may want to think about typesetting the table in landscape mode, especially as the table has nine columns, each containing non-trivial amounts of information.

Here's my suggestion, which makes use of the rule-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{rotating,caption,tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}[!h]
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % default: 6pt

\caption{A summary of classification results on the free flowing traffic dataset} \label{tab 4.2}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} c *{7}{C} c @{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{4}{@{}c}{No.\ of vehicles used for classication, by size} &
\multicolumn{5}{c@{}}{Classification accuracy, by classifier}\\
\cmidrule(r){1-4} \cmidrule(l){5-9}
Total & Small & Medium & Large & 
$K$-nearest neighbor & Nearest centroid & Naïve Bayes & Multilayer neural network & Ensemble\\
\midrule
952 & 594 & 199 & 159 & 90.9\% & 89.4\% & 91.1\% & 89.3\% & 91.8\% \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: The previous suggestion is based on the assumption that the table will ultimately contain more rows. If that's not the case, you may want to think about breaking up the table into two parts, each one containing just two columns. With such a setup, there would be no need to render the material in landscape mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % default: 6pt

\caption{Summary of classification results on the free flowing traffic dataset} \label{tab 4.2}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}lr@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{No.\ of vehicles used for}\\ \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{classication, by size} \\[0.25ex]
\midrule
Small  & 594 \\
Medium & 199 \\
Large  & 159 \\[1ex]
Total  & 952 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{@{}lr@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{Classification accuracy, by classifier}\\[0.25ex]
\midrule
$K$-nearest neighbor & 90.9\% \\
Nearest centroid     & 89.4\% \\ 
Naïve Bayes          & 91.1\% \\
Multilayer neural network & 89.3\% \\[1ex]
Ensemble             & 91.8\% \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for the use of `\cmidrule(r){1-4} \cmidrule(l){5-9}`—didn't know about that one

Comment: @Holene - Thanks! Indeed, the ability to apply left-hand and right-hand trimming to `\cmidrule`s is one of several great improvements of the `booktabs` package over the basic-LaTeX `\hline` and `cline` instructions.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this? I've added

- the `booktabs` package which provides the `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\bottomrule` and `\cmidrule{}`
- the `tabularx` package which provides the `tabularx` environment with the `X` column which support multiline content (strictly speaking not necessary after I removed all the explanatory text in the cells,
- the `multirow` package to horizontally align the vehicles variables a bit,
- the `siunitx` package for proper formatting of units (percentages in your case)
- the `caption` package to style the caption a bit, and provide better spacing between the (now quite massive) caption and the table, and
- the `geometry` package as I have no idea what kind of page layout you work with, and the table needed some more page width :p

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,siunitx,multirow}
\usepackage[hang,bf,small]{caption}
\usepackage{geometry}

\newcommand{\totNumV}{N_{V,\mathrm{tot.}}}
\newcommand{\smallV}{N_{V,\mathrm{s}}}
\newcommand{\medV}{N_{V,\mathrm{m}}}
\newcommand{\largeV}{N_{V,\mathrm{l}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \caption{A summary of classification results on the free flowing traffic dataset, where $\totNumV$ is the total number of vehicles used for classification, $\smallV{}$, $\medV{}$ and $\largeV$ are the number of small, medium and large vehicles used for classification, respectively. $K$, $C$, $\mathit{NBC}$, $M$ and $E$ are the K-nearest neighbor classifier,  Nearest centroid classifier, Naïve Bayes Classifier, Multilayer neural network classifier and Ensemble classifier, respectively. }
  \label{tab 4.2}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{9}{X}}
  \toprule
  \multirow{2}{*}{$\totNumV{}$} & \multirow{2}{*}{$\smallV{}$} & \multirow{2}{*}{$\medV{}$} & \multirow{2}{*}{$\largeV{}$} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{Classification accuracy}}\\  
  \cmidrule{5-9}
  & & & & $K$ & $C$ & $\mathit{NBC}$ & $M$ & $E$ \\
  \midrule
  952 & 594 & 199 & 159 & \SI{90.9}{\percent} & \SI{89.4}{\percent} & \SI{91.1}{\percent} & \SI{89.3}{\percent} & \SI{91.8}{\percent} \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

producing

[image]